# How do you get an exception when jsoup times out?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

So what I want to do is when my Jsoup connection times out I want to bring up an alert dialog. Right now it does nothing. It just skips over there error and doesn't catch a timeout exception or crash. I'm new to java so I'm not sure how to catch this sockettimeoutexception and reroute it to another method. Can someone tell me how to go to another method when jsoup time out?

```
 private void waterLevel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 try {


levelDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://waterdata.usgs.gov/va/nwis/uv?site_no=02037500roop").timeout(3000).get();

 }  catch (SocketTimeoutException a) {
     Log.e("MyAPP", "Exception----------A!", a);
     a.printStackTrace(); 
     alertdialog();
 }   catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("MyAPP", "Exception----------E!", e);
 }

 for (Element table : levelDoc.select("table[id=table_07_00065]")) {
     String tableText = table.text();
     depthArray = tableText.split(" ");
     waterLevel = Double.parseDouble(depthArray[4]);
     tvWaterLevel.setText(depthArray[4]+"FT");
     if(waterLevel >= 5.0 && waterLevel < 9.0){
        tvAlert.setText("LIFE JACKET REQUIRED");  
     }
     else if (waterLevel >= 9.0){
         tvAlert.setText("HIGH WATER PERMIT REQUIRED");
     }
     else{
         tvAlert.setText("");

     }
     }



}
```

So I add changed the code to this and it gives me what i want:

```
private void waterLevel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 try {


levelDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://waterdata.usgs.gov/va/nwis/uv?site_no=02037500").timeout(4000).get();

 }  catch (SocketTimeoutException a) {
     Log.e("MyAPP", "Exception----------A!", a);
     a.printStackTrace(); 
 }   catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("MyAPP", "Exception----------E!", e);
 }


 tvWaterLevel.setText("");
 for (Element table : levelDoc.select("table[id=table_07_00065]")) {
     String tableText = table.text();
     depthArray = tableText.split(" ");
     waterLevel = Double.parseDouble(depthArray[4]);
     tvWaterLevel.setText(depthArray[4]+"FT");
     if(waterLevel >= 5.0 && waterLevel < 9.0){
        tvAlert.setText("LIFE JACKET REQUIRED");  
     }
     else if (waterLevel >= 9.0){
         tvAlert.setText("HIGH WATER PERMIT REQUIRED");
     }
     else{
         tvAlert.setText("");

     }
     }
 if (tvWaterLevel.length() < 1){
     connectionAlarm();
 }


}
```

Comment: Maybe you could read the content of the URL to a file and have JSoup read from that file instead? This way you decouple the timeout problem from the actual reading

Comment: That would work but then the data may not be reliable. It just depends on when the last time the jsoup was able to read the URL.

Comment: So I thought about it and this may not be the correct answer but it works. I added  if (tvWaterLevel.length() < 1){connectionAlarm();}
 
  
 }